# Why content binding is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, binding

I try to use with data binding in content of labal in the xaml
For display to integer or string from View Model,
But binding is not working, not updating.

This my code:

In the xmal:

```
<Window x:Class="Calculator.View.Calculator"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calculator.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Calculator.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Calculator" Height="500" Width="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:Calculations x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">   
       <Label Content="{Binding Calc.Result, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="60"/>
    </Grid>
```

In xaml.cs I added porperty Calculations from view model:

```
public partial class Calculator : Window
    {
        private readonly Calculations Calculations = new Calculations();

        public Calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = Calculations;
        }
    }
```

in the View MOdel:

```
  {
        private CalculatorModel calc;
        
        public CalculatorModel Calc
        {
            get { return calc; }
            set { calc = value; }
        }
  }
public class CalculatorModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string result;

        public string Result
        {
            get { return result; }
            set
            {
                result = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Result");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to you set the `Result` and `Calc` properties? What do you expect to be displayed?

Comment: Your model (View Model) having the property for `CalculatorModel` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Ideally, only the view model implements the interface and your `CalculatorModel` should not. Also make sure that you are binding your view model to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different intances of `Calculations` class. One created in code-behind (`Calculations Calculations = new Calculations()`), and another in markup (`<vm:Calculations x:Key="vm"/>`).

Window operates with `calculations` instance, but displays `vm` instance. Keep only one of them, e.g.:

```
public partial class Calculator : Window
{
    private readonly Calculations calculations = new Calculations();

    public Calculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        calculations = (Calculations)this.Resources["vm"];
    }
}
```

Replacing DataContext (`DataContext = Calculations;`) *could* have worked, but new DataContext is set for Window, and not picked up by Grid, because Grid explicitly sets its DataContxt to StaticResource

Answer (score 1):

Remove your XAML resource and let the root `Grid` inherit the `DataContext` from the parent window, i.e. your XAML markup should look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Calculator.View.Calculator"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calculator.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Calculator.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Calculator" Height="500" Width="350">
    <Grid>
       <Label Content="{Binding Calc.Result, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="60"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then it should work if you set the corresponding property of the `Calculations` field in `Calculator.xaml.cs`.

Depending on how you set the property, you may need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the view model class as well.